# Angular Form Trouble Binding to Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a simple Angular form with a textbox and some hidden fields. This form is recycled many times on my page.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="form.jobAppForm" class="pitch-form" novalidate>
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" ng-value="window._token">
        <input name="user_id" type="hidden" ng-value="<%= current_user.id %>">
        <input name="job_description_id" type="hidden" ng-value="j.id">
        <input name="company_id" type="hidden" ng-value="j.company_id">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="apply-textbox" id="pitch" name="pitch" ng-model="jobApp.pitch"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input class="apply-submit-btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit Application" ng-click="createApplication(jobApp)" onClick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sending…';">
</form>
```

In my controller I have a `newApplication` method that initializes `$scope.jobApp` and then a `createApplication` method that sends a post request to the server. If I log the value of `$scope.jobApp` when `createApplication` is called, all the attributes are still set to null. Only the `pitch` attribute seems to be bound. If I enter a `pitch`, that is bound to the scope, but nothing else is. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Why is `pitch` bound but none of the other attributes? Here are my controller methods.

```
$scope.newApplication = function() {
    console.log('new app')
    $scope.form = {}
    $scope.jobApp = {
        token: null,
        user_id: null,
        job_description_id: null,
        company_id: null,
        pitch: null
    };
};

$scope.createApplication = function() {
    var jobAttributes = $scope.jobApp;
    console.log(jobAttributes)
    if ($scope.form.jobForm.$valid) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/applications',
            data: jobAttributes,
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'}
        }).success(function(data, status){
            console.log('success');
        }, function(err){
            alert("Failed to save job! Server responded with: " + err)
        });
    };
}
```

Note: I've tried setting `ng-model="jobApp.attribute"` for the other attributes as well as using `value=` rather than `ng-value=` to no effect.

Comment: You are using ng-model on the pitch field, but ng-value on all the others.  That's probably the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @HaukurHaf, you need to use ng-model on the form field.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="form.jobAppForm" class="pitch-form" novalidate>
<div style="display:none;">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" ng-model="jobApp.token">
    <input name="user_id" type="hidden" ng-model="jobApp.user_id">
    <input name="job_description_id" type="hidden" ng-model="jobApp.job_description_id">
    <input name="company_id" type="hidden" ng-model="jobApp.company_id">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="apply-textbox" id="pitch" name="pitch" ng-model="jobApp.pitch"></textarea>
</div>
<input class="apply-submit-btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit Application" ng-click="createApplication(jobApp)" onClick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sending…';">
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that was the problem. I also had to use ng-init to set the default values for my hidden inputs.